# Multiple errors after updating Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, and I stared a new Xamarin Forms app:
Create New project - Cross Platform App (Xamarin)
Blank App, and I chose Portable Class Library (PCL)
The app compiles and runs.
Now I right click the solution and choose Manage Nuget packages for solution, and it tells me I'm running version 23.3.0 and I should update to 25.4.0.1

After the update and 3 VS reboots, it gives me a host of errors I have been trying to solve for an hour including googling.
All theme related.

I tried removing the styles.xml file all together.  I removed the theme from the reference to the theme from the manafest and it keeps putting it back.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I have not written any code.

[image: VS erors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin Forms requires a specific version of the Android Support libraries. Do not update them.

Delete your project and create a new one.

It is possible to get round this limitation by ensuring you are using a specific version of Android and by updating all Android SDK's, but for a beginner I would recommend just using the support libraries that are installed alongside Xamarin Forms.

Comment: So to be clear, no matter what "Manage Nuget packages says", I should not update the package to the latest Xamarin version.  That is the answer I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: Use Nuget to update only Xamarin Forms to the latest stable version. It will also update any Android support packages it needs. Do not update the Android support packages yourself.